# Need a word that means "the worst that can happen"

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning

On the subject of weather and climate change, I'm wondering if there's a word that sums up "the worst case scenario"? At the moment I'm stuck on *amplitude*, as an expression of the field of/variations in outcomes... But I'm looking for something better! Ideally I'm looking for a tidy expression signifying maximum possible effect: *The something something*... (Not apocalypse etc) I know it exists, I just can't put my finger on it.

Many thanks for any help.

Comment: What do you mean by "apocalypse etc?" Are there specific words you're not interested in, other than apocalypse? I also wonder if the frequent use of the phrase "worst-case scenario" might reflect the absence of the term you seek.

Comment: If you ask me, surely the 'nuclear winter' scenario is as scary as it can get in the OP's scheme of things.

Comment: I think, Katherine, that "apocalypse" or "apocalyptic" felt somehow emotionally invested (and perhaps too total). But I completely agree, the over-popular "worst-case scenario" has become such everyday speak that I feel we've lost the more articulate version!

Comment: Thank you, Peter, although I think maybe "nuclear winter" is too much the result and not enough chain-of-events, if you see what I mean?

Answer (score 1):

Well,

The first word that comes to mind is ***Cataclysmic***.

From [Dictionary.com](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cataclysmic?s=t)

**cataclysmic**
(or cataclysmal)

Adjective

1. of, relating to, or resulting from a [cataclysm](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cataclysm).
2. of the nature of, or having the effect of, a [cataclysm](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/cataclysm) :
   *cataclysmic changes*.

=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=

**cataclysm**

Noun

1. any violent upheaval, especially one of a social or political nature.
2. *Physical Geography*: a sudden and violent physical action producing changes in the earth's surface.
3. an extensive flood; deluge.

But, to borrow a phrase from "*Doomsday: 10 Ways the World Will End*", I like the expression ***Extinction-level event***.  That certainly seems like it would be the worst-case scenario.

HTH.

Comment: I'd go along with an "extinction-level event" and suggest that the nuclear winter, if and when this happens, is the ultimate event. I think this is more likely to happen before global warming fully kicks in as the harbinger of doomsday in our temporal world on planet earth.

Comment: "Cataclysm" is a great word, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How about **doomsday scenario**?

Oxford English Dictionaries:

> [*doomsday*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/doomsday): the last day of the world's existence; a time or event of crisis or great danger: [as modifier] ‘in all the concern over greenhouse warming, one doomsday scenario stands out’

It's hard to imagine anything worse happening than *doomsday*. We can all put our heads between our knees and kiss our asses goodbye.

Comment: Thank you! I'm hoping the one cannot happen without the other i.e. the amount of infinite yoga I would need in order to pucker up and successfully put lips to butt means we have a good while on this planet yet.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, *the **extreme*** works, the assumption being that we are considering only the negative (undesirable) direction. Else, typically (in the most simplistic case) there are at least two *extremes* as in the minimum and maximum. Your own consideration of *amplitude* actually implies magnitude of the extreme (with respect to a reference point/measurement).

> 'the *extreme* to which climate can change.'

ODO:

> **[extreme](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/extreme)**
>   *NOUN*
>   **1.1** The highest or most extreme degree of something:
>   ‘extremes of temperature’

Answer (score 0):

[Catastrophic](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/catastrophic) fits your description

Comment: It really does, and is less final than "apocalyptic" (which is good for what I'm writing) - many thanks!